# Spyder (python 2.7) - why do scripts run if I hit run button, but not if I type script name in command line?

Tags: python, spyder, cwd

New to python/spyder. I am having trouble running scripts the way I want to. Quck example using the following script:

```
# Demo file for Spyder Tutorial
# Hans Fangohr, University of Southampton, UK

def hello():
    """Print "Hello World" and return None"""
    print("Hello World")

# main program starts here
hello()
```

I have saved this as hello.py. When I type hello() into my command line, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

However, if I hit the run button with this script open in the Editor, it runs just fine, and prints Hello World. I can *then* type hello() into my command line and it runs just fine.

Could someone please explain to me why this is?

My general goal is to save a startup.py script that I can run from the default cwd, which changes my cwd to where I want to save all of my code.

Answer (score 2):

`hello` isn't defined until you execute the `def hello` statement. You haven't run the script yet so that line hasn't been executed. After you have run the script, `hello` has been defined.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. I'm a Matlab user getting used to python.

Comment: Similar question, in that I'm wondering why I can't execute a "startup" script in my command line, but it works if I hit the run button. I have written a startup script that import some things, and changes the cwd (see below). I'd like to simply be able to run this from the command line, or stick it within an if statement at the beginning of other scripts that I write, in order to ensure that my cwd is what I want it to be. The startup code looks something like this:

Comment: import os, sys, numpy as np, scipy as sp

Comment: os.chdir('myNewDirectory') #myNewDirectory is just some directory where I save all my python code

Comment: So, that startup script is saved to the default cwd. I can hit the run button to execute it, but I can't run startup from the command line -- I get the error "NameError: name 'startup' is not defined." Just wondering why I can't run this script from the command line even though I have the correct cwd.